# How to execute code after authentication in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-signals, django-middleware

I want to execute one or more functions after a user logs into my site. How is this possible? I looked into Middleware. Djangobook says that I'll need this to run a piece of code on each and every request that Django handles. However, I just need the code run when the authentication happens successfully.

**Note:** I am using Django Allauth for authentication and I don't have any view of my own to log in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html), there is a signal `allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in` which gets triggered when a user logs in. This can serve your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tap into Allauth's [signals](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html). Specifically the user logged in signal

> ```
> allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in(request, user)
>
> Sent when a user logs in.
> ```

So add code similar to the following in your project.

```
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in

@receiver(user_logged_in, dispatch_uid="unique")
def user_logged_in_(request, user, **kwargs):
    print request.user
```

This code should be in a place that's likely to be read when django starts up. models.py and views.py are good candidates.

Comment: Can you update this answer to include just a little more code, so that it's clear where `receiver` and `user_logged_in` get imported from, and how to make sure this function is then called "on startup"? The signals documentation no doubt has that *somewhere*, but having it in this answer will help a lot more people (myself included)